# Setting timeout interval globally for Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

I use Alamofire throughout my project like so:

```
Alamofire.request("http://my.api.com", method: .get, parameters: ["some": "thing"], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: myHeaders)
```

Is there a quick way to set a timeout across all of my request like above? I've tried the following without luck

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
>     configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
>     let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
> ```